# python convert string to content of the string

Tags: python, django, string, django-templates

What I get:

```
names = """[{"lname": "HORJLAND", "fname": "Birger"}, {"lname": "LAMERS", "fname": "Edmund"}]"""
```

What I want:

```
names_list = [{"lname": "HORJLAND", "fname": "Birger"}, {"lname": "LAMERS", "fname": "Edmund"}
```

How can I get names_list from names?

I get the names variable from a django template and I want to parse it in a template tags by looping over it and get name['fname'] and name['lname'] like:

```
for name in names:
   print(name['fname'])
```

> TypeError: string indices must be integers

But since I get names and not names_list my loop is looping over each character of names!

```
for name in names:
   print(name)

[
{
"
l
n
a
...
```

Quite stupid but I can't figure out how to do it...

Comment: `import json` and `names_list = json.loads(names)`.

Comment: So easy! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ast.literal_eval` to find the content of a string. Sample code:

```py
from ast import literal_eval
a = """[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]"""
b = literal_eval(a)
print(type(b))  # <class 'list'>
```

PS: DO NOT use `exec(a)` or `eval(a)`! They have security risks. For example, if you use `eval('__import__("os")')`, the user can get access to your computer.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
from ast import literal_eval

names = """[{"lname": "HORJLAND", "fname": "Birger"}, {"lname": "LAMERS", "fname": "Edmund"}]"""

for name in literal_eval(names):
  print(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `json` module, since and if, the contents in the string is valid JSON.

Try,

```
import json
names = """[{"lname": "HORJLAND", "fname": "Birger"}, {"lname": "LAMERS", "fname": "Edmund"}]"""
names_list = json.loads(names)
print(names_list)
# [{'lname': 'HORJLAND', 'fname': 'Birger'}, {'lname': 'LAMERS', 'fname': 'Edmund'}]
```